# Drawing Transition table

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata, transition

I want to draw the following diagram
[image]
Yellow colour can be avoided. I have no clue how to draw this. I have not used `\tikzpicture` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point. Everything is customizable. Make some search, you'll find many interesting things.

[image: Automata]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\tikzset{every state/.style={fill=yellow!50}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]

  \node[initial,state] (q0)                    {$q_0$};
  \node[state]         (q1) [below right of=q0] {$q_1$};
  \node[state,accepting]         (q2) [above right of=q1] {$q_2$};
  
  \path (q0) edge [bend left]   node {0} (q1)
             edge [loop]        node[above] {1} (q0)
        (q1) edge [bend left]   node {1} (q0)
             edge               node {0} (q2)
        (q2) edge [loop]        node[above]{0} (q2)
             edge               node[above] {1} (q0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT: QUOTES LIBRARY

Following Zarko's suggestion, here's a new (lighter) version using `quotes` library and which produces exactly the same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,quotes,positioning}

\tikzset{every state/.style={fill=yellow!50}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,
                        node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
    
      \node[state,initial]   (q0) {$q_0$};
      \node[state]           (q1) [below right = of q0] {$q_1$};
      \node[state,accepting] (q2) [above right = of q1] {$q_2$};
      
      \path (q0) edge [bend left,"0"]   (q1)
                 edge [loop,"1" ']      (q0)
            (q1) edge [bend left,"1"]   (q0)
                 edge ["0"]             (q2)
            (q2) edge [loop,"0" ']      (q2)
                 edge ["1" ']           (q0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you not use `positioning` and ` quotes`  libraries˙ and than write for example `\node[state]  (q1) [below right=of q0] {$q_1$};` and `\path (q0) edge [bend left,"0"]  (q1)  edge [loop,"1" ']  (q0)`?  I is a bit shorter ... (anyway '1)

Comment: Yes, you're right. You already did that on another of my posts and I voted for yours. It's probably a question of habit. I don't use the `quotes` library very often but I'll try and think of it from now.